# postfix multiple smtpd_sender_login_maps

Tags: postfix

I'm using postfixadmin with included vacation feature.
support@mail-server.cc is a regular mail-account i'm using to send e-Mails from different services via smtp auth - in this case in the vacation.pl file for to send the out-of-office message with the users FROM address.
Everything is okay unless i enable smtpd_sender_login_maps.

As per postfix documentation the smtpd_sender_login_maps could have more than one lookup tables.
I'm trying to use two, mysql and a hashed db file with additional ones where i use the support@mail-server.cc but a different FROM address.
Each of them are working but when i specify both of them only the first table is working.

So, when having the mysql query first only the aliases from the mysql db can be used as FROM address:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps     = 
   mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias.cf,
   hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_sender_aliases.cf
```

and the vacation autoresponder is failing:

```
Jan 10 00:34:01 mx1 postfix/submission/smtpd[16856]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx1.mail-server.cc[195.88.238.11]: 553 5.7.1 <alex@mail-server.cc>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user support@mail-server.cc; from=<alex@mail-server.cc> to=<alex5000@gmx.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost.localdomain>
```

When i specify the hashed db file first then the vacation autoresponder is working but the user is no longer able to send e-mails with his account or aliases:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = 
   hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_sender_aliases.cf,
   mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias.cf
```

log entry:

```
Jan 10 00:49:40 mx1 postfix/submission/smtpd[26589]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[192.168.200.100]: 553 5.7.1 <alex@mail-server.cc>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user alex@mail-server.cc; from=<alex@mail-server.cc> to=<alex5000@gmx.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.200.100]>
```

content of /etc/postfix/allowed_sender_aliases.cf:

```
@mail-server.cc         support@mail-server.cc
```

content of /etc/postfix/virtual_alias.cf:

```
# alias mapping
hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = vmail
password = xxxxx
dbname = mail
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address = '%s' AND active = '1'
```

Is there something wrong or is it really that only the first table is used?
Strange is that the user is not able to send e-mail's anymore when using the hash table.

Comment: How is your vacation autoresponder configured? It ought to just be dropping mail directly into the queue, but it reads like it's making an authenticated network connection on port 587.

Comment: That's correct, its connecting via 587 with starttls like a regular client.
I'm currently testing and finalizing my setup, if i get all working i will move webmail and postfixadmin to a separate host keeping things separated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After much head-scratching, I think I found the answer. Postfix defines a "match" when searching `sender_login_maps` as any lookup that succeeds, but the *result* of that lookup is not considered.

**`tl; dr`: If you intend to use a *union* of the results from all mappings in `smtpd_sender_login_maps`, instead of just taking the *first* succeeding lookup result, the mappings must be combined somehow (e.g. via SQL `UNION` or `unionmap`).**

At its core, it's a surprisingly simple problem caused by Postfix's short-circuiting behavior when doing mapping lookups. Buckle up for the ride, this is a long answer...

---

### Background

From the Postfix documentation on sender login maps:

> **smtpd_sender_login_maps** (default: empty)
>       ...
>
> Specify zero or more "type:name" lookup tables, separated by whitespace or comma.
>    *Tables will be searched in the specified order until a match is found.*

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps

The purpose of using `smtpd_sender_login_maps` is to validate whether the currently authenticated SMTP user is allowed to send from a given FROM address in their message. It's a powerful feature to restrict the addresses a client can send from based on who the authenticated SMTP user is.

**`smtpd_sender_login_maps` has many use cases, e.g.:**

- Prevent a user from logging in and sending a message as someone else
  *> Bob can send as `bob@example.com`, but can't send as `alice@example.com`*
- Allow multiple users to send from a single shared address neither of them own
  *> Bob and Alice can both send as `marketing@example.com`*
- Allow a single user to send from multiple addresses they own
  *> Alice can send as both `alice@example.com` and `alice.smith@example.com`*
- Allow an admin to send messages from many addresses (even owned by others)
  *> Tracy, the IT admin can send as anyone `.*@example.com`*
- And more... (remember, lookups can be via TCP socket, SQL query, regex, etc.)

---

### Example Scenario

We're going to investigate this use-case in particular:

> - Allow an admin to send messages from many addresses (even owned by others)
>     *> Tracy, the IT admin can send as anyone `.*@example.com`*

Imagine a setup where we have Postfix and MySQL running on a mailserver.
There are 3 users stored in the DB who can authenticate via SMTP with postfix:

- `alice@example.com`: can only send from `alice@example.com`,`alice.smith@example.com`
- `bob@example.com`: can only send from `bob@example.com`,`bob.jones@example.com`
- `admin@example.com`: should be able to send from *any* `.*@example.com` address

Regular users can only send from their main address and their aliases, but we want to allow the admin to be able to masquerade as *any* sender without restrictions. In real life, this type of setup is useful whenever a user needs to be able to send from many addresses `.*@example.com` using only one SMTP login (e.g. if the addresses are dynamically-generated or belong to other users).

The normal approach is to use `smtpd_sender_login_maps` to achieve this setup.

> #### Example Config
>
> **`/etc/postfix/main.cf`:**
>
> ```
> ...
>
> smtpd_sender_login_maps = 
>     mysql:/etc/postfix/sender_logins.cf,
>     pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_overrides.cf
>
> ...
> ```
>
> MySQL is checked first, then the pcre is checked only if the mysql lookup returned 0 results.
>
> ---
>
> **`/etc/postfix/sender_logins.cf` (`mysql`):**
>
> ```
> hosts = 127.0.0.1
> user = postfix
> password = yourDatabasePasswordHere
> dbname = mail
> query = SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='%s'
> ```
>
> This mapping checks the DB and returns the normal SMTP user for a given FROM addr, e.g.:
>     `alice@example.com         -> alice@example.com`
>     `bob.jones@example.com     -> bob@example.com`
>
> ---
>
> **`/etc/postfix/sender_overrides.cf` (`pcre`):**
>
> ```
> /.*@example.com/     admin@example.com
> ```
>
> This mapping matches *all* `@example.com` FROM addrs and returns the admin SMTP user, e.g.:
>     `.*@example.com -> admin@example.com`

---

### The problem

**The behavior the user expects:**

1. Postfix looks up the FROM addr in the first `sender_login_maps` db
2. it finds a matching entry for the FROM addr
3. the returned SMTP user != logged in user, **so we try the next mapping db**
4. Postfix looks up the FROM addr in the next `sender_login_maps` db
5. it finds a matching entry for the FROM addr
6. the SMTP user == logged in user
7. **Postfix sends the message succesfully**

**What actually happens:**

1. Postfix looks up the FROM addr in the first `sender_login_maps` db
2. it finds a matching entry for the FROM addr, **so the lookup process stops**
3. the returned SMTP user != logged in user
4. **Postfix rejects the message**

---

### Explanation

The issue is that Postfix doesn't check both mappings and merge the results, instead it stops the lookup process the moment it encounters the *first* matching lookup returning any SMTP user.

If the returned SMTP user doesn't match the currently authed user, it won't proceed to lookup the address in the next database, it'll just immediately `DENY`.

The same lookup conflict can happen with any two mappings that share keys, e.g. two mysql databases `mysql:...,mysql:...`, not necessarily just a `pcre` with `/.*/` or `/.*@example.com/`. Any exact match or wildcard match like `@example.com  someuser@example.com` in the first mapping will take precedence and prevent the second mapping from being queried at all.

#### Scenario 1: `alice@example.com` tries to send from `alice@example.com`

✅ This works fine, the email is sent because the address matches the sender as expected.

1. `alice@example.com` logs in via SMTP to send a msg from `alice@example.com`
2. `alice@example.com` lookup in `smtpd_sender_login_maps` returns `alice@example.com`
3. Sending succeeds, `alice@example.com` == SMTP authed user `alice@example.com`

#### Scenario 2: `admin@example.com` tries to send from `alice@example.com`

❌ This does not work, the email is rejected because the SMTP authed user `admin@example.com` doesn't match the first lookup result `alice@example.com`.

1. `admin@example.com` logs in via SMTP to send a msg from `alice@example.com`
2. `alice@example.com` lookup in `smtpd_sender_login_maps` returns `alice@example.com`
3. Sending fails, `alice@example.com` != SMTP authed user `admin@example.com`
   `postfix/smtpd[16645]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from webmail.mailserver[192.168.1.5]: 553 5.7.1 <alice@example.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user admin@example.com; from=<alice@example.com> to=<bob@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.example.com>`

#### What if we flip the order of the mappings?

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = 
    pcre:...,        # moving the pcre mapping above mysql makes it worse
    mysql:...
```

Flipping the order of the mappings so that the pcre file is checked before mysql won't fix the problem. It even makes it worse because the catchall `.*@example.com` will overshadow all the real users in MySQL and prevent any user other than `admin@example.com` from sending email.

When it looks up `alice@example.com` in the pcre file, it returns `admin@example.com` as the only allowed user and fails before it ever checks the mysql database.

---

### The solutions

#### A. Make the `smtpd_sender_login_maps` disjoint

If the mappings don't contain any overlap in keys, then the order doesn't matter, and any lookup that doesn't match the first db will proceed to check the subsequent ones as expected.

Mappings earlier in the list cannot have any "catchall" or wildcard keys or they will match everything and overshadow results from later mappings.

#### B. Join multiple lookup results in SQL with `UNION`

If you're using the `mysql` table type for your `smtpd_sender_login_maps` mappings, then you can control the SQL query run when doing an address lookup and you may be able to join multiple mappings at the SQL level.

Assuming all your mappings are accessible in the same MySQL database, you can concatenante the results of multiple address lookups at the SQL level using a `UNION` statement like so:

`main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sender_logins.cf
```

`sender_logins.cf`:

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = postfix
password = yourDatabasePasswordHere
dbname = mail
query = SELECT email
            FROM users
            WHERE email='%s'
        UNION SELECT destination
            FROM aliases
            WHERE source='%s'
        UNION SELECT email
            FROM users
            WHERE wildcard_sending=1
```

In this example we would set `admin@example.com` to have `wildcard_sending=1` in SQL, and then it would be returned with every lookup result along with the normal user and alias matches, e.g.

```
alice.smith@example.com    -> alice@example.com,admin@example.com
bob@example.com            -> bob@example.com,admin@example.com
```

#### C. Use `unionmap` to combine multiple mappings

If you're using Postfix 3.0 or above, you might be able to try using the new `unionmap` feature, which performs a lookup to all the mappings at once and concatenates the results together.

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = unionmap:{
        mysql:/etc/postfix/sender_logins.cf,
        pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_overrides.cf }
```

With this setup, the mysql results will be concatenated with the pcre lookup results, e.g.

```
alice.smith@example.com    -> alice@example.com,admin@example.com
bob@example.com            -> bob@example.com,admin@example.com
```

See http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types **unionmap** for more info.

---

### Sources

> Word "match" is thus to be taken here in the narrowest sense: just a
>   matching  address, not a matching (address, login name) pair.
>   Moreover, when a matching  address is found, the lookup chain is
>   immediately halted with a binary  reject/accept decision.

- https://www.mail-archive.com/postfix-devel@postfix.org/msg00677.html
  (I highly recommend reading this entire mailing list thread for more context)
- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps
- http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists
- http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types
- http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294300/postfix-prevent-users-from-changing-the-real-e-mail-address
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.postfix.users/X7Wj_nSEyKI
- https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie/relaying-smtp-authentication